# How to save Gantt and PERT as a GIF image?

Tags: ms-project

I'm working with MS Project, and I have created a Gantt chart. How would I save a Gantt and PERT file as a GIF image? I did it once, but I cannot find it anymore.

Comment: Here's one from Superuser.

http://superuser.com/questions/456318/how-to-export-gantt-chart-from-ms-project-as-an-image

Cheers

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about saving images, not project management. Please see [help/on-topic] for the list of topics our site targets. Hope this helps and good luck! :)

Comment: After discussing on our site's [Project Management Meta site](http://meta.pm.stackexchange.com/q/670/34), it seems this is indeed on-topic after all. I've edited this a bit to clarify that this is about MS Project, and I've reopened the post. In the future, it's a good idea to be clear in your questions so folks like me don't misunderstand. Hope this helps and thanks for participating! :)

Answer (score 3):

For Microsoft Project 2007, go to **Report menu** and then **Copy Picture...**. It will show the following popup:

[image]

Choose "**To GIF image file**" option to save the Gantt chart as a GIF file.

Comment: Oh yes, my answer (in reference to MS-Project 2010) calls up the same dialog, where I see here (but somehow had never noticed before!) that it includes the means to save directly to GIF!

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of a way to directly save to GIF, but I frequently use the "Copy" functionality (Under Clipboard functionality on the Task tab of MS-P 2010) to grab an image snapshot of the project Gantt into the cut buffer, from where it can be pasted into an email, or a Word document, or into Paint to be saved as a JPG or whatever.

If you are on a prior version of MS-Project, the same functionality is there and it is behind the menu button that looks like a little camera.